# How to add a script to startup and shutdown in debian?

Tags: debian, scripting

the title pretty much sums it up.

how do I add a startup.sh and shutdown.sh of my server app to the startup and shutdown sequence of the Debian OS?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On Debian, service & application boot and shutdown scripts should be placed into `/etc/init.d/`.

Debian provides an example script `/etc/init.d/skeleton` that you can modify to your taste for your particular application.

Once it's in place, call:

```
# update-rc.d YOURAPP defaults
```

To have Debian add the `/etc/rc?.d/` symlinks for you.

If you prefer a menu or graphical interface, take a look at the `sysv-rc-conf` or `ksysv` package.

Answer (score 6):

Since Debian Jessie, the old `init` program has been replace by **`systemd`**.

Check it out yourself.  Run: `ls -l /sbin/init` and see what it's pointing to.  These days it points to `systemd` (`/sbin/init -> /lib/systemd/systemd`), a newer and better initialization program.

---

**SO THE CHOSEN AND OTHER ANSWERS HERE ARE NOW OUTDATED**

---

*While you can still install scripts the old way with System-V tools, it's not a good idea generally speaking.

`man systemd.service` says:*

> *If a service is requested under a certain name but no unit configuration file is found, systemd looks for a SysV init script by
> the same name ... and dynamically creates a service unit from that
> script.  This is useful for compatibility with SysV.  Note that this
> compatibility is quite comprehensive but not 100%.*

---

### For newer Debian systems (i.e. Jessie, Stretch, Buster, etc...)

It's easier than you think. (-:

Here's the new and preferred method to install boot-up or shutdown programs.

With `systemd` you first want to create a **unit file**.  A unit file is mostly declarations, not code.

Then you'll use the **`systemctl`** command to **enable** or **start** that unit.

`systemd` does much of the work for you, making it easy, for example, to have a critical program automatically re-start if it crashes or is otherwise killed.  Also it shuts down your program where and when it should by default with no extra work on your part.

---

**Start to learn about `systemd` here:**

[From Debian](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/unix-services.html#sect.system-boot) and [elsewhere](https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-and-using-systemd) and [etc](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files)  and [etc](https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-getting-a-grip-on-units/).

---

**Man pages to start with:**

`man systemd.unit`  -- About unit files in general
`man systemd.service`  -- About service unit files, e.g. daemons, and single run programs.

`man  systemctl`  -- Command line user interface
`man journalctl` -- View log of what systemd has done

`man systemd`  -- About the init program itself

---

There are also a variety of other types of unit files, e.g.

`man systemd.target` - for groups and common synced targets.

Once you've digested the basics above, then dig in with `man -k systemd` to find other related man pages.

---

---

Whatever you do, on Debian **do not use any of these**:

- `update-rc.d` --install and remove System-V style init script links
- `sysv-rc-conf` -- Run-level configuration for SysV like init script links
- `runlevel` -- Print previous and current SysV runlevel
- `BUM` -- **B**oot **U**p **M**anager - a graphical runlevel editor
- `systemadm` -- Graphical frontend for the systemd system and service manager
  (BTW, the author told me by email that it's too broken now.)

---

---

### AN EXAMPLE:

This unit file starts up the NoIP.com daemon when I boot-up, and shuts it down when I shutdown.

*This daemon, from time to time, sends my current IP address to update my DDNS  (**D**ynamic **DNS** (**D**omain **N**ame **S**erver)) provider's data base, thus keeping my domain name pointing at my computer wherever it travels to.*

This unit files is located on my system in this settings file: `/etc/systemd/system/noip2.service`

Here's what's in the unit file:

```
#   Comments can only go at the beginning of the line!

[Unit]
Description=Start the NoIP IP update daemon.  This runs every 30 minutes and reports our current IP to NoIP.com to update Love2d.ddns.net.
Documentation=https://no-ip.com/
Documentation=file:///nobak/Installers/NoIP/noip-2.1.9-1/README.FIRST


[Service]
# 'forking' because process returns after starting daemon (traditional unix daemon).
Type=forking

# This program runs and returns, leaving the running daemon
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/noip2

# Be in no hurry to start this.  Max nice is +19.
Nice=15

# If it dies for any reason, then restart it
Restart=always


[Install]
# Installs a hook to use this unit file when the system boots or shuts down
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

**Manually run** a unit file, (e.g. for testing):

- **start** with `$ sudo systemctl start noip2`.
- **restart** with `$ sudo systemctl restart noip2`.
- **stop** with `$ sudo systemctl stop noip2`.

**Configure system** to automatically run a unit file when starting up or shutting down:

- **begin using** with `$ sudo systemctl enable noip2`.
- **end using** with `$ sudo systemctl disable noip2`.

**View log**

- `$ sudo journalctl -u noip2`

Answer (score 4):

You can call your script from **/etc/rc.local**, prior to the line that says *exit 0*

As for shutting down your app, I would suggest putting a script in **/etc/rc0.d**.  You need to name it with an uppercase **K**, and then a 2 digit number which specifies the order these scripts are run, and then a name. It will be called with a parameter "stop", but you can ignore this for a simple stop script.

Comment: Why would you stuff around with rc.local when you've already got to fiddle with /etc/rcX.d anyway?

Comment: rc.local is the proper place for simple startup stuff - don't need to deal with start/stop parameters, etc.  But it doesn't have the ability to shut-down a process.  The rc0.d stuff is a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 3):

For startup have a look at [this](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Making_scripts_run_at_boot_time_with_Debian).

For shutdown, create a link / copy your script into one of the /etc/rcX.d folders where X is the runlevel that you want it to execute at.  0 is the shutdown runlevel for Debian I believe.

Comment: This is the shutdown info I needed.  Thanks for this, @squillman.

Comment: One should also note that reboot (on Debian) uses runlevel 6; so if one wants to halt the program cleanly on _both_ halt and shutdown, they should link to both `/etc/rc0.d` and `/etc/rc6.d` on they SysV-init systems.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest is to modify existing scripts, works in my system, used for sounds :)

- startup, modify `/etc/init.d/rc.local`, add your sh at the end of the file, before : 
  (it will execute it right before login "screen")
- shutdown, modify `/etc/init.d/halt`, add your sh at the beginning of the file, just after initial comments
  (it will be executed before actual shutdown command, that is called by this script file
- reboot, same as shutdown, but in `/etc/init.d/reboot`